# How do I use SQL Server 2005 and 2008 versions on the same operating system?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I always use SQL Server 2008, and now my new projects need SQL Server 2005. I searched solution to create scripts on SQL Server 2008 and use it on SQL Server 2005, however their mdf file on their 2005 cannot be attached to my SQL Server 2008 instance. So, I tried to install 2005 at the same time.

I have also tried to give the instance of SQL Server 2005 a name instead of using default instance, still cannot find that instance. Can I use SQL Server Management Studio 2008 to open SQL Server 2005 instances?

Or do you know how to attach SQL Server 2005 .mdf file on my SQL Server 2008? Why I cannot even attach that file?

Comment: It's possible, although you probably have to [install 2005 first](http://serverfault.com/questions/58194/running-sql-server-2005-and-2008-on-same-machine). Can you explain why you can't attach the 2005 database to your 2008 server? How are you doing it and what happens? This is [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx), so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use later version of SQL Server Management Studio to attach to older versions of the engine without difficulty (it is backward compatible).

To use a SQL Server 2005 database on 2008 or later backup and restore the database, don't detach and reattach.  The restore process will automatically upgrade the database format as you restore.